# How to get on screen image coordinates using pyautogui in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyautogui

When I run this script:

```
import pyautogui

x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('key7.png')
pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SMART/Desktop/locate.py", line 3, in <module>  
    x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('key7.png')  
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I want to locate then click a button on the calculator:

like the number 7. I want to locate the key and get it's center `x` and `y`

Any suggestions to do this task using python 2.7 with pyautogui?

Comment: when you say "it returns none", do you mean x and y are none? Could you provide the error message, if this is an error?

Comment: @AhmedAbdulla check the code i have uploaded

Answer (score 1):

I've also had issues with using pyautogui locate image. Ways I've improved the search have been

1- search a smaller area with pyautogui.locateOnScreen('someButton.png', region=(0,0, 300, 400))

2- Taking the screen shot with pyautogui (not snipping tool etc)

3- pyautogui doesn't use transparency in the search so if the PNG has transparency (as it needs to be pixel perfect) that could throw it off

You may also want to try grey scaling the search

Answer (score 1):

use confidence perimeter while locating something on screen...

```
x3, y3=pyautogui.center(pyautogui.locateOnScreen("./imp_icons/followss.JPG", confidence=0.7))
pyautogui.click(x3,y3)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is code which works for me:

```
>>>import pyautogui
>>>button7location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('calc7key.png')
>>>button7location
(1416, 562, 50, 41)
>>>x, y = pyautogui.center(button7location)
>>>x, y
(1441, 582)
>>>pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

this is my key7 image [image: key 7 image]

Comment: `>>> import pyautogui
>>> button7location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('key7.png')
>>> button7location
>>> print button7location
None
>>> button7location
>>> x, y = pyautogui.center(button7location)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    x, y = pyautogui.center(button7location)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 401, in center
    return (coords[0] + int(coords[2] / 2), coords[1] + int(coords[3] / 2))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: Please make sure while running the code your calculator is visible on screen

Comment: your `button7location` shows `None` means button is not visible

Comment: this code:`import pyautogui

button7location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('key7.png')

print button7location`                 is returning `None` when i run it ,the                                         calculator is visible

Comment: the calculator is on the screen i can see it and i can see the button 7 100%